# ¿cuando presiono un input tipo submit se enviara toda la informaccion o cada input respeta a su formulario?

Tags: html

que pasas si  tengo varios formularios separadados dentro de una misma pagina web , cada formulario tiene su respectivo input tipo submit la pregunta es *¿cuando presiono un input tipo submit se enviara toda la informaccion(ose si presiono el input del formulario1 la info del formulario2 tambien se enviara?) o cada input respeta a su formulario?*, no tengo codigo porque recien voy a empezar y me dijeron que no se puede , si es asi espero que me puedan ayudar ...gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1):

Como dice la especificación:

> The `input` element represents a button that, when activated, submits
>   the form.
>
> ---
>
> El elemento (`input type="submit"`) representa un botón que, cuando es activado (se hace click en él), envía el formulario.
>
> <sub>- [W3C Recommendation, apartado 4.10.5.1.15](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#submit-button-state-(type=submit))</sub>

Esto quiere decir que **cada formulario** responde solamente al click de su respectivo botón submit.

Podemos verlo con un ejemplo.

Aquí en el DOM tenemos dos formularios distintos, cada uno con su botón. Luego en Javascript tenemos un código genérico que escucha el envío de cualquier elemento de tipo `form`.

Podrás ver que al enviar uno u otro formulario el código sólo capturará los datos de **ese formulario**. El formulario que se envió es identificado aquí mediante: `$(this)`.

Puedes hacer la prueba en directo:

```js
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $thisForm = $(this);
  var frmData = $thisForm.serialize();
  var msgInfo = `Se envió el formulario: ${$thisForm.prop('id')} <br />Con los datos: ${frmData}`;
  console.log(msgInfo);
  $("#info").html(msgInfo);

});
```

```css
#info {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Formulario 1</h3>
<form id="frmOne" action="#">
  Nombre: <input type="text" name="ibxNombre" value="Pedro"> Apellido: <input type="text" name="ibxApellido" value="Sanz">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar Form. 1">
</form>
<hr />
<h3>Formulario 2</h3>
<form id="frmTwo" action="#">
  Nombre: <input type="text" name="ibxNombre" value="Juan"> Apellido: <input type="text" name="ibxApellido" value="Mercado">
  <input type="submit" value="Enviar Form. 2">
</form>
<br />
<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando pulsas en un submit se envía sólo el form al cual pertenece. Incluso cada form podría tener distintas páginas «destino», pero sólo se va a enviar la información del form al que pertenece el botón.